# Executing programs without having to specify a directory?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, init-script

Why is it that I have to type `/etc/init.d/apache2 (args)` in order to run apache??

Isn't there a way to just `apache2 args` ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't normally type a command to run Apache: it starts when the system boots. Scripts in `/etc/init.d` start services and are executed automatically at boot time, if your system is set up correctly. With most distributions, services are enabled by default and will start unless you've done something to disable them.

If you've stopped Apache and want to restart it, `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` is the normal way — or preferably `service apache2 start`. It would be of little use to have a shorter command since this is not something that you would do as part of normal system use. Commands that are intended for common use are can be executed without specifying their full path; these commands are in directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable (which Windows imitates).

Answer (score 6):

You should probably be using the `service` command to start it.

`service apache2 start`

And the apache arguments should be in your `/etc/apache2` structure.

Answer (score 4):

That is because /etc/init.d/ is not set in $PATH.

> It's essentially a :-separated list of directories. When you execute a
>   command, the shell searches through each of these directories, one by
>   one, until it finds a directory where the executable exists. ( http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs348/unix_path.html )

Comment: While this is true, some shells will expand aliases, search for functions, and check it's internal hash prior to searching PATH.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to invoke a command (script or binary executable) that's not within the reach of your `PATH`.

Those methods are good to know - but, if you find yourself pulling all the more fancy stunts just to execute commands, then that would indicate a less than optimal system design.

Let's say this is your script, called `s`, and you place it in `/home` (to make it unreachable, as `/home` is most certainly not in your `PATH`):

```
echo "The first argument is: $1"
echo "The second argument is: $2"
```

Three ways to still reach it, without giving the absolute path, are:

An alias: `alias salias='/home/s'`

A function: `sfunc () { /home/s $@ }`

A link: `ln -s /home/s slink`

The first two, if you'd use them again, you'd put in your shell initialization file (`.bashrc` for bash, `.zshrc` for zsh, etc.). To use the link (the third case), you'd have to put it in a directory included in you `PATH`, or, you'd invoke it explicitly, with an absolute path (e.g., if you're in the same directory, `./slink one two`).